# Livewire\Exceptions\ComponentNotFoundException - Unable to find component: [Livewire.Tasks-Board]

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

I created the component using the following command

```
php artisan make:livewire TasksBoard
```

This is the Livewire Tasks component

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class TasksBoard extends Component
{
    public $tasks;

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->tasks = auth()->user()->statuses()->with('tasks')->get();
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.tasks-board');
    }
}
```

This is my blade file

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<div class="md:mx-4 relative overflow-hidden">
    <main class="h-full flex flex-col overflow-auto">
        @livewire('Livewire.TasksBoard', ['task' => $tasks])
    </main>
</div>

@endsection
```

I have tried all these possible solutions but none of them work

Attempt 1

```
php artisan livewire:discover
```

Attempt 2

```
@livewire('Livewire.TasksBoard', ['task' => $tasks])
```

Attempt 3

```
@livewire('Livewire.Tasks-Board', ['task' => $tasks])
```

Attempt 4

```
@livewire('Livewire.TasksBoard')
```

Attempt 5

```
@livewire('Livewire.Tasks-Board')
```

Comment: try `@livewire(tasks-board, ['task' => $tasks])`?

Comment: @H.A. Consider marking the answer below as the accepted answer by clicking the checkmark below the vote buttons for the answer. It helps others find (and know) an answer was the solution to your problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

livewire documentation is clear on how to handle its directives, so your mistake is in this line

```
@livewire('Livewire.TasksBoard', ['task' => $tasks])
```

instead declared it as:

```
@livewire('tasks-board', ['task' => $tasks])
```

Comment: Thank you. This solves it.